# pg-admin "WHERE" clause is not working correctly

Tags: php, pgadmin

I want to show data,based on previous week.
 my query for pg-admin is

```
"SELECT * FROM event  WHERE datetime BETWEEN NOW()-INTERVAL '6 DAYS' AND NOW()"
```

it is working fine in pg-admin editor and shows me correct data,but when i implement this query to php code it doesn't show the required result.
 my php code is

```
$queryStr ="SELECT * FROM event  WHERE datetime BETWEEN NOW()-INTERVAL '6 DAYS' AND NOW()";
    $result = pg_query($conn,$queryStr);
    if (!$result) {
        echo "An error occurred in query.\n";
        exit;
    }
    $result = pg_fetch_assoc($result);      
    return $result;
```

it shows me only one row any solution?

Comment: Possible you must use operator like ''>'' or ''<''

Comment: `pg_fetch_assoc()` only fetches the **current** row from the result set, you'll need to loop it - something like `while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) { ... }`. See the [example on the manpage](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: thanks CD001  its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use something like below :

```
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{ 
echo $row['id']; 
echo $row['author']; 
echo $row['email']; 
}
```